# Why did Doom3 create their own containers versus use a library?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've been looking through the Doom3 gpl code again recently and noticed that the "Containers" section of the idLib library has a unique implementation of 50+ year old data structures like a linked list. You can find the implementation here:

[Doom 3 Linked List](https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl/blob/master/neo/idlib/containers/LinkList.h)

My question is - why do so many games choose to reinvent the wheel instead of using a library like STL or BOOST? Is there a performance reason?

Comment: Because your own containers are a whole lot faster! STL etc. have to account for all kinds of usage patterns. And they contain a whole lot of code that a game won't use. Also games are real time systems. In the clutch sometimes you have to fix a container used in an inner loop. It would be a pain to have to patch STL or Boost.

Comment: The Doom 3 Engine's cute name is [id Tech 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_4). Assuming it builds on previous revisions, the first releases would predate both a standardized STL and Boost. That might explain why it still uses its own linked list implementation.

Comment: Because at the time Doom 3 was created, C++ was barely standardized and compiler support was more than bad for most stuff. That'd be my *guess*, anyways.

Comment: And they probably had a linked list implementation from when it was written in C and so just wrapped a class around the struct

Comment: It's interesting how this question has been closed as not constructive. There are different reasons for having your own containers, I wonder if the question instead of begin Doom3 and ID was about EA and their implementation of the standard libarary containers (which are not standard compliant), would it have been closed? Where I work we have our own (non-standard compliant) standard libraries and the reason is that we use a different allocator model than the one in the standard.

Comment: Never question the all-powerful [Carmack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Carmack).

Comment: @David, well, a more general formulation (`is rolling your own linked list better than using STL?`) is already quite subjective (and probably a dupe) but may attract better answers indeed. However, tying the question to the Doom engine only makes things worse IMHO. There's only a very light chance someone from id will step up and enlighten us, and in the meantime we're left to betting on performance, legacy (as I'm guilty of in my previous comment), code size and whatnot, which is the very definition of `not constructive` in my book.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Do you know why EA rolled their own containers? There are people that never worked in EA and do know... (I used to know and but forgot, and I never worked for EA)

Comment: @David - Having myself written the question, I also thought this was a little strange to close. Is it corner case? Perhaps. But it's one of the most popular open source engines on the market. I guess I could change it to something more general, but I think it would actually have less traffic.